# Рамка в элементах списка ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

у меня есть стиль, в нем нарисована рамка. Когда я задаю его через атрибут `android:background="@drawable/style"` то он применяется на весь элемент ListView, когда через  `android:listSelector="@drawable/style"` то только при нажатии на элемент (очевидно)

Что нужно сделать, чтобы рамка обволакивала каждый элемент списка ListView?

Я в этом деле новичок, поэтому камнями не бейте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#808080" />
</shape>
```

Код класса:

```
public class tab1contacts extends Fragment {
ListView listView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1concacts,container,false);
        ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // определяем строковый массив
        final String[] catNames = new String[] {
                "Лабораторна робота №1", "Лабораторна робота №2", "Лабораторна робота №3", "Лабораторна робота №4", "Лабораторна робота №5",
                "Лабораторна робота №6", "Лабораторна робота №7", "Лабораторна робота №8", "Лабораторна робота №9", "Лабораторна робота №10",
                "Лабораторна робота №11", "Лабораторна робота №12", "Лабораторна робота №13","Лабораторна робота №14","Лабораторна робота №15",
                "Лабораторна робота №16", "Лабораторна робота №17", "Лабораторна робота №18","Лабораторна робота №19"
        };
        // используем адаптер данных
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catNames);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Код xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.SmartRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srlEnableOverScrollBounce="true"
        tools:context=".ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">
    
    <com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.header.FalsifyHeader
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
        />
    
    <com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.footer.FalsifyFooter
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
        <ListView
            android:listSelector="@drawable/style"
            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
            android:divider="@null"  />

    </com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.SmartRefreshLa

yout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо использовать собственную разметку для элементов списка. Именно в неё и можно будет прописать фон. Проще всего, в вашем случае - скопировать файл `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, прописать в нём ваш фон и его использовать вместо скопированного при инициализации адаптера.